Adjust regex to also match partial expression
Is there a generic way to wrap an existing regex to also accept partial matches?
For example verifying an IPV4 address one can use ((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d{1,2})(?:\.(?!$)|$)){4})
Now this works for

10.0.10.1

But not for

1
10





10.0
10.0.
10.0.1
10.0.10
10.0.10.

I want to provide a generic way to wrap the existing regex (or any else) without modifying it into a new regex that accepts any amount of partial ip addresses.
UPDATE: The intention of this is to use it as a mask for a text field thus I need to allow partial strings otherwise it would only work by inserting the complete IP at once e.g. via pasting from clipboard.

of the "partial" inputs you specified many are no valid IPv4 addresses - so what is your actual requirement for matches? I don't think it is possible to wrap a regex for a complete IPv4 address with more stuff to match only parts - only vice versa would maybe be feasible, but the best solution would be to start from scratch

The requirement is to use this as a mask for a text input field. With the complete match it only works if I paste the whole IP from clipboard thus inserting all characters at once ... otherwise if  i start typing it does not match the regex thus nothing gets accepted.

That's not how regex works. Maybe move the verify process to blur or form submit event instead of change?

You probably need to make a new pattern that accepts 1-4 groups, something like this (regex101). Note that your current pattern allows such as 0.00.0.00 which does not look to be desired.

For interactive validation during input, maybe something like [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*; it can be made more complex if you like, of course, but this is the fundamental pattern.

If you use a masking plugin, handling partial input is usually built in.

I suggest:
^(?:\b\.?(?:1\d{0,2}|[3-9]\d?|2(?:[0-4]\d?|5[0-5]?|[6-9])?|0|$)){0,4}$

demo
Feel free to change the last quantifier to {1,4} if you do not want the empty string to be valid.
Notices:

consecutive dots are avoided using a word-boundary at the start of the main group.
this word-boundary also avoids a dot at the start the field.
about the group that contains numbers description:

branches are ordered by probability of the starting digit (111 numbers start with 1, 77 start with [3-9], etc.)
the last branch is the end of the string anchor $ to allow a trailing dot. It is more efficient to do that and less problematic than making the whole group optional




A simple solution is the following:
^(?=\d)(?:\.?(?!\.)(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)?(?=$|\.)){1,4}$

where:

(?=\d) ensures that the regex starts with a digit.
\.?(?!\.) matches an optional period not followed by another period. Not that in the first part of the address a period cannot be matched (since the string must start with a digit).
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)? is the right pattern for a single numerical part of the address. It is optional because the it is requires that a partial address may end with a period.
(?=$|\.) ensures that a numerical part of the address is not directly followed by another numerical part.

See a demo here.
P.S. Note that your original regex also matches wrong cases, as 10.09.1.1. Moreover, if it is used for non-full matches, it also captures

56.1.1.1 in 256.1.1.1 and
10.0.10.10 in 10.0.10.10.1


This regular expression also matches numbers bigger than 255 as long as no more than 1 dot has been entered (e.g. 300.9999) - which will probably not lead to a valid IP address in dot notation even if the user continues typing.

@cyberbrain Thank you! I've updated the pattern.

As already mentioned in my comment I cannot think of a "wrapper" solution, but you could use this regex for your purpose:
^(?:(?:(?:1\d\d)|(?:[1-9]?\d)|(?:2[0-4]\d)|(?:25[0-5]))\.){0,3}(?:(?:(?:1\d\d)|(?:[1-9]?\d)|(?:2[0-4]\d)|(?:25[0-5])))?$

Please note that it doesn't accept whitespaces so you might have to trim your input string before validation or extend it for the whitespace at start and end.
UPDATE:
I extended the regular expression to not accept leading zeros within the octets, as @logi-kal pointed out, as this would indicate a number in the octal system, where the regex would not match all allowed numbers.
Nevertheless I would recommend that you do not use this regular expression for a validator, if you want to validate an input field for a complete IPv4 address, as it simply does not do that job - it validates also partly entered addresses as correct! You should rather put your validator onto a different event like when the field looses focus or before the request is actually sent.
This behaviour is widely seen in applications, so the user can finish entering a field even if a partial input is not valid.

This regex also matches 10.09.1.1.

@logi-kal thx for the heads up - I fixed this.
